# $this->"variable value" OOP PHP

Tags: php

I'm wondering if it's possible, and in case it is, how shoud I achive that:

`$this->id`  <-- i have such thing. but to make it more usable i'd like to have `$this->(and here to change the values)`

for ex:  I might have `$this->id  $this->allID  $this->proj_id`

how can I make so that actually I have `$this->($myvariable here, that has a unique name in it)`?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use this:

```
 $variable = 'id';
 if ( isset ( $this->{$variable} )  ) 
 {
    echo $this->{$variable};
 }
```

Comment: I'd use $this->{$variable} just in case $variable evaluates to something containing a hyphen.  $this->some-thing isn't a valid expression whereas $this->{'some-thing'} would work just fine.

Comment: @GordyD  -  ok, I have smth like that actually in my OOP PHP...

In my class I have  protected static $tableID = 'sched_id';

and in the class that is extended I have smth like this:

$this->static::$tableID   

but it doesn't work..

Comment: Again, $this->{$variable} is IMHO better. In your solution, second dollar sign can be easly unnoticed.

Comment: @Crashspeeder - Thanks for comments guys. I have updated my answer further to your suggested improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

An example of using it is here :

```
class myClass {
    /**  Location for overloaded data.  */
    private $myProperties = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->myProperties[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->myProperties))
        {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) manual on the PHP site.
With that, it could look like:

```
<?php
   echo ${'this->'.$yourvariable};  
?>
```

Comment: I think $this->{$yourvariable} looks far better.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `call_user_func` and pass the parameters as `array` instead.

```
public function dynamicGetterExample()
{
    $property = 'name'; // as an example...
    $getter = 'get'.ucfirst($property);

    $value = call_user_func(array($this,$getter));
    if (empty($value)) {
        throw new \Exception('Required value is empty for property '.$property);
    }

    return $value;
}
```